# Why my Absinthe GraphQL Subscription doesn't work?

Tags: graphql, phoenix-channels, absinthe, absinthe-subscription

My Schema:

```
 subscription do
    @desc "Subscribe to drawing change"
    field :drawing_change, :drawing do
      # arg(:drawing_id, non_null(:id))

      config(fn _args, _resolution ->
        {:ok, topic: "*"}
      end)
    end
  end
```

When I do

```
subscription {
  drawingChange {
    data
    name
  }
}
```

I get this error `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Log:

```
[debug] Processing with Absinthe.Plug
  Parameters: %{"query" => "subscription {\n  drawingChange {\n    data\n    name\n  }\n}", "variables" => nil}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[debug] ABSINTHE schema=DrawingApiWeb.Schema.Schema variables=%{}
---
subscription {
  drawingChange {
    data
    name
  }
}
---
[info] Chunked 200 in 107ms
```

Here are my rest of the set up:

User socket:
`use Absinthe.Phoenix.Socket, schema: DrawingApiWeb.Schema.Schema`

Endoint:
`use Absinthe.Phoenix.Endpoint`

Router:

```
forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL,
      schema: DrawingApiWeb.Schema.Schema,
      socket: DrawingApiWeb.UserSocket
```

All this happens before I commit any change to any context. Whatever the issue is, it should be in the setup. I have followed the exact instruction in the Absinthe-GraphQL book and Pragmatic Studio Video, and I verified it with the https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/subscriptions.html

Still the same error.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

I did not set up `ws://localhost:4000/socket` in the Graphiql.

All good now. 
cheers